# Install a fileset on AIX

Tags: aix, fileset

I'm trying to install the fileset bos.adt.syscalls.5.3.0.40 on AIX 6.1 using the following command :

```
/usr/lib/instl/sm_inst installp_cmd -a -Q -d 'test' -f '_all_latest'  '-c'  '-g' '-X' '-G' '-V 2' '-Y'
```

test=the directory which contains the fileset. 
but I'm getting this error :

```
Input device or directory does not exist
```

However I used the same command line on AIX 5.3 but it gave an error saying that I need the base level fileset . 
Can any one help me with this ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to do it through smit?  It might insulate you from command-line errors.

Comment: Thanks Tripp for your reply ...I can't use SMIT, because I'm accessing to AIX via telnet ...

Comment: There is a text version of SMIT.  `smitty`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you are getting the error saying that you need the base level fileset, is because you are trying to install an update fileset. The .40 in the fileset version (bos.adt.syscalls.5.3.0.40) indicates that is an update, for you to be able to install that version of the fileset, you need to have bos.adt.syscalls.5.3.0.0 installed first.
A bigger issue with what you are trying to to do is that fileset bos.adt.syscalls.5.3.0.40 is an AIX 5.3 fileset and you said you are running AIX 6.1, you cannot install a bos.adt fileset from AIX 5.3 on AIX 6.1